# html css position sticky option is not working

Tags: html

So I'm new to html and trying to use position: sticky but it is not working. I don't know why? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
div.sticky {
      position: "sticky";
      top: 0;
      background-color: green;
      border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you try delete quotation marks?

Comment: Yep, no quotes around "sticky" should do it.

Comment: Please attach your html code too and it's good to make it snippet for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `sticky`. That should do the trick!